# Simple global variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<input type="hidden" value="test" id="first" />
<input type="hidden" value="working" id="second" />

function set(){
    //others operations
   var clone = $('#second').clone();
    //others operations
}
var clone = $('#first').clone();

console.log($(clone).val());
var clone = set();
console.log($(clone).val());
```

This return me:

```
test
test
```

but should be:

```
test
working
```

How can i make it? I know - i can return value from function and assign to a variable, but i can't use return in my function with this value.  Is possible to make?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n2KSn/)

Comment: You should read a book about the basics of javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to return a value in your function, you shouldn't set clone to the returned value (which will be undefined). Also, you should only declare clone once, in your global scope...

```
var clone;

function set(){
    //others operations
   clone = $('#second').clone();
    //others operations
}
clone = $('#first').clone();

console.log($(clone).val());
set();
console.log($(clone).val());
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n2KSn/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Just return the value

```
function set(){
  var ret;
   //others operations
  ret = $('#second').clone();
   //others operations
  return ret;
}
```

Also, you only need to specify `var` when you declare the variable (the first time you use it):

```
var clone = $('#first').clone();

console.log($(clone).val());
clone = set();
console.log($(clone).val());
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n2KSn/3/)

Comment: but this not execute second others operations

Comment: @user3047403: let me fix that